# Bad memory allocation in Python LinkedList

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, python-2.7, linked-list

I have some problem regarding a Python simple linked list and its memory consumption.

This is the code:

```
import sys

class Record:
    def __init__(self,elem):
        self.elem=elem
        self.next=None

    def size(self):
        print 'elem.size = ', sys.getsizeof(self.elem)
        print 'next.size = ', sys.getsizeof(self.next)


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.first=None
        self.last=None

    def addAsLast(self,elem):
        rec=Record(elem)
        if self.first==None:
            self.first=self.last=rec
        else:
            self.last.next=rec
            self.last=rec

if __name__=="__main__":
    l=LinkedList()
    r = Record(1)
    r.size()

    maxx = 10000000
    r = range(1, maxx)
    print 'size of r: ', sys.getsizeof(r)
    print 'size of r[n-1]: ', sys.getsizeof(r[maxx-2])

    for i in r:
        if(i% (maxx/10) == 0): print '.'
        l.addAsLast(i)
    print "The End"
```

My problem is this: running this script consumes **1.7 GB of my RAM**.

Output is:

```
elem.size =  12 
next.size =  8 
size of r:  40000028
size of r[n-1]:  12
```

so, let's do some quick math:

10 millions of Record.

Each Record got 12 bytes (elem) + 8 bytes (pointer to next one) = 20 Bytes

20 bytes * 10 millions = 200.000.000 bytes = **190.7 MB**

Even if I must consider the list allocated by range() function (approx. 30 MB) how can I manage that huge gap of memory consumption? Have I done some stupid mistake in this code? I hope the answer will make me feel ashamed and sorry to have asked it but, up to know, I'm just wondering what's happening!

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Not that it makes up the large gap, but you should alter the ```size``` method of ```Record``` and make it print ```sys.sizeof(self)``` instead of the two component elements.  It's 32 bytes, not 20 because there is overhead in the class structure.

Comment: fragmentation will add something, I guess. I would try something like `recpool=[None]*10000000; ... rec=recpool[j]; j+=1` and see what happens.

Comment: also, try `gc.disable()`.

Comment: If you [use `__slots__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots), you will seriously reduce the size of your data structure, since `__dict__` will be eliminated. Also, linked list is a very memory-uneconomical structure unless your payload is large. Avoid it unless you need fast removal from the middle of a very long list, and even then consider skip lists, etc.

Comment: @Elazar: I've used gc.disable() but the result is always +2.0 GB approx.
I'll try using __slots__ asap, never heard about that so I'll go read some stuff. Every example is welcome. 

And, unfortunately, I'm quite compelled to use this kind of LinkedList this time, I just need to save the most memory I can

Comment: well, consider moving to C :)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> class Record:
...     def __init__(self, elem):
...             self.elem = elem
...             self.next = None   
... 
>>> r = Record(1)
>>> sys.getsizeof(r)
72
```

Or am I missing something?

Also, on my system:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(1)
24
>>> sys.getsizeof(None)
16
```

Comment: Thinking about it now: 56 or 72 bytes, it still shouldn't add up to 1.7GB. At 56 bytes, that math has you at ~600MB. I'll keep thinking about it :)

Comment: 56+28=84. round up - 88. 88*10000000~=0.88GB. add fragmentation and GC overhead, and you have something close.

Comment: remember that GC may consume I think something like 150% of original resources, depending on how it works.

Comment: Sophomoric, but... where'd you get that 28 from?

Comment: `sizeof(1)` on my machine.

Comment: I usually don't worry much about Python memory use, but I believe each instance of a class is implemented as a hash table, and hash tables have some overhead.  You can get around this using the "slots" mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Altered print-out as follows :

```
class Record:
    def __init__(self,elem):
        self.elem=elem
        self.next=None

    def size(self):
        print 'Record size = ', sys.getsizeof(self)
        print 'elem.size = ', sys.getsizeof(self.elem)
        print 'next.size = ', sys.getsizeof(self.next)
```

Output :

```
Record size =  72
elem.size =  24
next.size =  16
```

So, each of my linked list nodes is 72 bytes x 10M should be 720MB, .72GB

I ran the program, and using top, saw that the memory overhead was 3.6G.
My elem size is double yours, and I am noticing double the total memory consumed as you are (3.6G, compared to 1.7G).

This must be due to extra python memory overhead, such as garbage collection.